# how I read from text file in python my dataset and applying the matrix on it

Tags: python, list, file, matrix, adjacency-matrix

**I want to apply adjacent matrix that take data from the file text and apply matrix then the output will be zeros and ones**

**this is my code of the dataset stored in file text**

```
mylist= ['T','C','A','G']

with open("codon2.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for i in range(0,len(mylist)):
         for j in range(0,len(mylist)):
            f_out.write('\n')
            for k in range(0,len(mylist)):
             f_out.write(mylist[i]+mylist[k]+mylist[j])
             f_out.write(' ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally assumed everything, hope this is what you are looking for. Following code, will set adjacency matrix (firstly containing only 0's), then convert 0's to 1's for adjacent nodes.

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, numNodes):
        self.adjacencyMatrix = []
        for i in range(numNodes): 
            self.adjacencyMatrix.append([0 for i in range(numNodes)])
        self.numNodes = numNodes

    def addEdge(self, start, end):
        self.adjacencyMatrix[start][end] = 1


# random example
edges_list = [[1, 2], [0, 1], [2, 3]]

# assuming number of nodes is 4
graph = Graph(4)

# converts 0's to 1's for adjacent nodes
for i in edges_list:
    graph.addEdge(i[0], i[1])

with open("codon2.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for i in graph.adjacencyMatrix:
        for j in i:
            f_out.write(str(j))
        f_out.write('\n')
```

Comment: i will try it @Rustem Qarayev

Comment: if i want to save as 0 and 1 i have the code but how to apply it @Rustem Qarayev

Comment: What do you mean when you say ''i want to save as 0 and 1"? Your output will be according to your input file. So, whatever you pass in your .txt file, it will be processed accordingly.

Comment: i want to apply adjacent matrix @Rustem Qarayev

Comment: How is your graph represented? Is it list of edges or is it adjacency list?

Comment: list of edges @Rustem Qarayev

Comment: @kkx I edited answer, check if this is what you are looking for.